# Google Analytics on AMP does not send custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

This used to work before but now when I add the following code snippet, from the Google Analytics AMP integration page, it does not make a network `collect` call for Google analytics https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/#extending_googleanalytics

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "requests": {
    "pageviewWithCd1Cd3": "${pageview}&cd1=${cd1}&cd3=${cd3}"
  },
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageviewWithCustom" : {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageviewWithCd1Cd3",
      "vars": {
        "title": "Classic Cars",
        "cd1": "registeredUser",
        "cd3": "automotive"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

I replaced the account with a real account starting with `UA`

I also have the analytics script tag included in the head tag:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
```

The pageview does fire a request to `collect` but the `cd1` and `cd3` do not get included in the query params nor does the values of cd1 and cd3 get passed in the query params of the URL.

Have others noticed this same issue starting November 17th onwards?

Comment: Could you add a URL sample?

Comment: It turned out to be a Chrome bug in that it did not show the XHR request to analytic's `collect` endpoint because it was redirected.

Comment: Analytics for AMP pages are not visible in regular GA Debug tool , we need to check in Google Tag Manager. 
Regarding the above example 'title' param is showing fine but 'cd1' , 'cd3' are not concatenated to the active url .
yes same issue with me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the related github thread on the Chrome error here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6740#issuecomment-268119523

Answer (score 1):

If somebody ends up here looking for solution how to send custom dimensions for AMP, that's what finally worked for me:

```html
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
    <script type="application/json">
      {
          "vars": {
              "account": "UA-XXX-XXXX"
          },
          "triggers": {
            "trackPageview": {
              "on": "visible",
              "request": "pageview",
              "extraUrlParams": {
                  "cd1": "dimension1Value",
                  "cd2": "dimansion2Value"
               }
            }
          }
      }
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

[Documentation link](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/configure-analytics/deep_dive_analytics/#appending-request-url:-extra-url-params)

Comment: Your example is incorrect. The "extraUrlParams" does not work inside of the triggers object. The "extraUrlParams" belongs at the same level as the "triggers" object and are passed for all the triggers that are defined.

Comment: @SmileIT it was correct and worked for me as expected. Everyone should switch to GA4, I believe, so the answer is outdated now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - using dp=${newPageName} where 'newPageName' is custom url

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "requests": {
    "pageviewWithCustomPageCd1Cd3": "${pageview}&dp=${newPageName}"
  },
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageviewWithCustom" : {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageviewWithCustomPageCd1Cd3",
      "vars": {
        "title": "Classic Cars",    
        "cd1": "registeredUser",
        "cd3": "automotive",
        "newPageName": "sample.html?amp=1&cd1=${cd1}&cd3=${cd3}"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```